# command not found: sudo

Tags: sudo, root

After reading about the [lately discovered vulnerability with sudo](https://thehackernews.com/2019/10/linux-sudo-run-as-root-flaw.html), I decided to update to 1.8.28 manually.
I downloaded deb file from `sudo.ws` and used `dpkg` to install it, and it failed due to lack of dependencies.

```
sudo dpkg -i debs/sudo_1.8.28-1_ubu1804_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 232031 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sudo_1.8.28-1_ubu1804_i386.deb ...
Unpacking sudo:i386 (1.8.28-1) over (1.8.27-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sudo:i386:
sudo:i386 depends on libc6.
sudo:i386 depends on libpam0g.
sudo:i386 depends on libpam-modules.
sudo:i386 depends on zlib1g.
sudo:i386 depends on libselinux1.
sudo:i386 depends on libaudit1.

dpkg: error processing package sudo:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
sudo:i386
```

After that I can't call `sudo` any more and it seems to be damaged cause I can locate it in `/usr/bin/sudo`:

```
l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 479K Oct 10 20:15 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Since there is no `Root` user available on Ubuntu I was wondering if there is any  solution other than rebooting as root in `recovery mode`?

### Update

Here is the output of `type` on `sudo`:

```
type -a sudo 
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
sudo is /bin/sudo
```

And `pkexec`doesn't seem to be working for me (no action. Only sitting there gazing at me)

The only option left is recovery mode which I have to postpone till end of the day and I'll let you know the result.

Comment: You should not be using `sudo_1.8.28-1_ubu1804_i386.deb`. Chances are you are on a 64bit Ubuntu server. Run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade all your pacakges, including `sudo`

Comment: The fix has been rolled out for all repositories alredy: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2019/CVE-2019-14287.html

Comment: @Kulfy Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: @hanxue I can't use `sudo` since it can't find it.

Comment: @pLumo Great news, but won't  help  me with my situation.

Comment: @Kulfy 
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo   sudo is /bin/sudo

Comment: Log in as root and install

Comment: @Kulfy `zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: @pLumo I'm trying that solution, but nothing happened. `pkexec apt install sudo` doesn't show any output

Comment: @hanxue I would if I could. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Please walk me through.

Comment: you might need to clean your failed manual sudo installation ... (just a guess). https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195794/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-installed-with-dpkg

Comment: @Kulfy `pkexec` doesn't seem to working for  me.

Comment: So please [edit] your question to show the exact commands you issued and their output.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found so far was rebooting as root in recovery mode and starting  networking service for it to download required packages and after all it's back to normal, but unfortunately 1.8.27 version

Comment: As per [USN-4154-1: Sudo vulnerability](https://usn.ubuntu.com/4154-1/), 1.8.27 is the version that fixes vulnerabilities for 19.04.

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks for the time. `Sudo`'s change log claims it happened on `1.8.28` so, maybe Ubuntu themselves managed  this issue.